# How to customize/convert bootstrap multiselect to single select conditionally w/o radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-multiselect

The HTML is as below:-

```
<select name="companyName"  id="ddlCompanyId" name="companyList" multiple="multiple" ></select>
```

I am using bootstrap-multiple.js and conditionally want to use single select without radio buttons.

thanks in advance!

Comment: so basically you want the same functionality like radio buttons but with checkboxes?

Comment: not exactly, like i want to clearselect all options which is not happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to remove/hide the radio buttons you can add a new style in your css or you can use the following event:

> [onDropdownShown](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onDropdownShow): A callback called after the dropdown has been shown.

To change from multi to single selection it's enough to toggle the html attribute **multiple="multiple"**, [rebuild](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods) plugin.

From comment:

> and how to clear selection on single select dropdown with bootstrap multiselect?
>
> [multiple](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-multiple): ....using the plugin for single selections (without the multiple attribute present), the first option will automatically be selected if no other option is selected in advance.

That means: you need to use jQuery [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) with an empty string to deselect each option.

```js
$('#ddlCompanyId').multiselect({
    onDropdownShown: function(e) {
        if (this.options.multiple == false) {
            this.$container.find(':radio').hide();
        }
    }
});

$('#btnToggle').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#ddlCompanyId').attr('multiple', function(idx, attr) {
        return (attr==undefined) ? 'multiple' : null;
    });
    // deselect ...
    $('#ddlCompanyId').val('');
    // rebuild the whole dropdown...
    $('#ddlCompanyId').multiselect('rebuild');
});


$('#btnToggleDisable').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($('#ddlCompanyId').is(':disabled')) {
        $('#ddlCompanyId').multiselect('enable');
    } else {
        $('#ddlCompanyId').multiselect('disable');
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <select id="ddlCompanyId" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnToggle">Toggle Multiselect</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnToggleDisable">Toggle disable</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and how to clear selection on single select dropdown with bootstrap multiselect?

Comment: val() worked for me. Another concern is that now with single select dropdown $('#myselectid').multiselect('disable') doesn't work.